# This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

Here is the structure of my sample addon:

[image: My Selenium-IDE structure]

Here is how I build my XPI file:

```
cd my-addon
C:\Progra~1\7-Zip\7z.exe a -r -y -tzip ../my-addon.xpi *
```

When I try to load the resulting xpi in Firefox, I get the following error:

> *This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.*

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of the install.rdf (and also chrome.manifest actually)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `install.rdf` or `chrome.manifest` or the `7z.exe` zip command isn't putting those files in the root of the resulting `xpi` file, without being able to see the contents of the install.rdf or chrome.manifest though I am guessing the issue is in there, but double check the `xpi` is being created properly too.

Comment: You were right, my `install.rdf` was an invalid xml file. I update it and everything works now.